# CSS-positioned canvas sized differently than other block elements (constraints on top left bottom right properties)

Tags: css, canvas, positioning

This puzzled me and is intriguing, I hope.

I'm interested if anybody can point me at the *source* of this difference in behavior in terms of CSS/ canvas specification, I know other solutions on how to fill the parent container so please no such answers.

Consider this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html, body, #container {
        height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
      }

      #container {
        position: relative;
      }

      #content {
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid red;
        background-color: blue;

        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <canvas id="content"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2zH5H/. This HTML results in the canvas being sized with the default width/ height the canvas spec calls for (300x150) instead of it filling the parent container as the CSS rules define. You can verify this works without any changes for any other block element, for example a div: http://jsfiddle.net/8AQVj/1/

Again, we're talking about the size of the element on screen, not the canvas context's dimensions. The behavior is consistent in Chrome, Firefox and IE so I guess it has to stem from specification somewhere but I couldn't find the relevant fragment.

Comment: I guess this have something to do with elements that have default size (as you have noticed): http://jsfiddle.net/8AQVj/2/

Answer (score 0):

The size attributes you have there for the canvas is set to auto which is the default for these attributes, and therefore you get the default size in this case. If you change it to inherit, then it will fill its parent container, even if its context specified in the tag itself is set to specific measures. Just to make sure I was right, I checked it in fiddle.

Comment: No, not really. Inherit will actually inherit the parent container's width and height and it's not the same as recalculating it based on top/left/right/bottom -- try making the border wider (10px) and you'll see the difference compared to my div example (the nested container will overflow when width/height are inherited).

Comment: 100% for the canvas size attributes can be used just as well to eliminate the overflow. As with all elements, there is a browser default. My point is that setting height and width to auto calls for the default and does not call for a calculated re-size to a parent. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, now I think see what you're getting at. The only thing I know is that canvas is a block element but acts like an inline-block element similar to images. This is why a default canvas does not span it's parent like many basic containing blocks like a div and form. However, there are idiosyncrasies with many block elements, take a look if you change canvas to p. As for a source for this, I will post one if I find one.